# last-child/last-of-type And [attr|=value]/[attr^=value]

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between for example p:last-child selector and p:last-of-type selector?

Also what is the difference between for example p[class|"hello"] and p[class^="hello"]

Comment: you can see these in w3schools itself.

Comment: RTFM: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you'd expect `p:last-child` matches the last child and `p:last-of-type` matches the last element of the type.
The difference between `p[class|"hello"]` and `p[class^="hello"]` is that the former is not a valid selector while the latter is.
Also, see the comment on your question.